# Generate a random integer between -2 and 1 inclusive

Tags: matlab

How can one generate a random integer between -2 and 1 inclusive?
I know if I take rand*(b-a)+a I would get random real number between a and b
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

$$\lfloor4\operatorname{rand}()\rfloor-2$$

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`randi`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/randi.html), which generates integers between 1 and the specified input argument:

```
randi(4)-3
```

If you don't have the `randi` function (it is included in newest versions of Matlab), you could use `rand` with `ceil`:

```
ceil(rand*4)-3
```